# How do I make sure a redirector page can be dismissed after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a javascript or html ad to test in my mobile app, however everytime I click on the banner link a white redirector page is left behind when I go back into the application. What can I add to my code to dismiss this after the link redirects to an external site?

Here's an example of what I use:

a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"target="_blank">
img src="http://imagehostingurl.com"/>

Comment: Can you show us your javascript, please?

Comment: Here is the Javascript I was using: <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"target="_blank"><img src="http://admarvel.s3.amazonaws.com/ads/adv13031/13757451074685_test_3.jpg"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

process the ad being clicked on with ajax therefore no redirection will be necessary on the referrer page. for example when the link is click an event handler is fired providing the ad id. the event calls a php script to log the ad being clicked in addition to opening a new window. An alternative could be to send the link to script on your sever that redirect to the provided link associated to the ad id. records of ads would have an ad id and a link.

$query = "SELECT from ads where ad_id =". $adid;

$res = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    header("Location: " . $row['link']);